# Unity 2D Cinemachine weird behavior for non rectangular confiner

Tags: unity, camera, platformer, cinemachine

I have been trying to emulate a sort of Megaman X4 way of following the player around platforming levels, where the camera is confined to certain boundaries of such levels.

However, all the tutorials and guides out there only show rectangular or square-shaped confiners for the virtual cameras, and not odd shapes like an L shaped confiner, when using a weirdly shaped confiner the camera just tends to snap from one position to another and the game ends up feeling bad when that happens.

I have tried solving this problem by using dolly tracks, which work nicely... But I end up having tons of virtual cameras to change to on sections that are weirdly shaped since the camera ends up also suddenly snapping on to weird positions on sharp turns and it also tends to get way off track, even when the settings of the virtual camera are configured to have very little damping and if there's no damping the camera just stutters all the time.

Is there a way to have this kind of behavior to confine a virtual camera to oddly shaped level boundaries?

Comment: Is using cinemachine a requirement, or would you accept answers that use a custom script to move a vanilla Unity camera, without cinemachine getting involved?

Comment: It's not a requirement to use cinemachine, but since we do need to change virtual cameras for secret areas we find cinemachine to be useful for that